# Is there a way to stop the already playing music when I clicked on another recyclerview item?

Tags: java, android

In my music player app, I am fetching the music files and storing it in recycler view.

when I clicked on a recyclerview item the music player layout will be shown and when I come back to that activity and click on other item, the previous music will keep on playing and along with that the new music is playing.

I tried

```
if (mp.isplaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```
if(mb.isPlaying){
    mb.stop;
  }  

  mb.prepare;
  mb.start;
```

If this solution doesn't work please share your code so I can help you.